# How to retrieve original coefficients after performing regression on normalised data without using Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am reading data from a file using `pandas` which looks like this:

```
data.head()

   ldr1  ldr2  servo
0   971   956     -2
1   691   825   -105
2   841   963    -26
3   970   731     44
4   755   939    -69
```

I proceed to normalize this data to perform gradient descent:

```
my_data = (my_data - my_data.mean())/my_data.std()
my_data.head()

       ldr1      ldr2     servo
0  1.419949  1.289668  0.366482
1 -0.242834  0.591311 -1.580420
2  0.647943  1.326984 -0.087165
3  1.414011  0.090200  1.235972
4  0.137231  1.199041 -0.899949
```

I perform multivariate regression and end up with fitted parameters on the normalized data:

```
Thetas:  [[ 0.31973117  0.45401309 -0.12941108]]
```

I would like to **plot the plane of best fit on the original data and not the normalized data** using the normalized thetas.

I used `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to perform multivariate linear regression and come up with the optimal fitted parameters. I know that the original thetas should be close to the following:

```
[   0.26654135   -0.15218007 -107.79915373]
```

How can I get the 'original' thetas for the original data-set in order to plot, *without* using Scikit-Learn?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

---

As per the answer below:

```
m
ldr1     731.891429
ldr2     714.080000
servo    -21.388571
dtype: float64
s
ldr1     168.392347
ldr2     187.583221
servo     52.904576
dtype: float64
```

I then proceed with:

```
original_thetas = np.dot(theta, s) + m
```

which yields:

```
original_thetas
ldr1     862.420572
ldr2     844.609144
servo    109.140572
dtype: float64
```

I am not sure if I am performing the calculation incorrectly or if the method presented does not work for the coefficients themselves.

Comment: I think I may have led you astray - [this post on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30876/how-to-convert-standardized-coefficients-to-unstandardized-coefficients) seems to suggest you may just need to divide by the standard deviation? The intercept is more complicated and needs the mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you just need to store the mean and standard deviations

```
m = data.mean()
s = data.std()
```

And then inverse the transformation

```
theta * s + m
```

Comment: @desertnaut I often second guess if this is right when being applied to the coefficients themselves!

Comment: Hmm... reading closely, you are right; this is certainly valid for the *data* themselves, but for the coefficients...?

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Yes this works for the data, wil ltry with the coefficients and get back to you.

Comment: How does this work out when `my_data.std()` differs for each column? For example I am doing `(g.flat[0]*s) + m` and get extremely small values.

Comment: @Rrz0 Can you add a print of s and m and theta to your question? the standard deviations and means are arrays, element per column, which is why it should work fine when different across columns

Comment: Edited, I see. Am I computing it wrongly then? The coefficients I get aren't anywhere close to what they should be. Oh! I think I found the mistake. Very stupid mistake form my end...

Comment: @Rrz0 That looks like the mean and standard deviation after you have done your transforms - you want to store the mean and standard deviation _before_ you do the normalisation.

Comment: You're right! I re-edited the question to include the proper values. Will see if I can get back to the original coefficients using the _proper_ `s` and `m` values. Thanks